# How to re-subscribe a stream table after unsubscribing in dolphindb?

Tags: dolphindb

How to re-subscribe a stream table after unsubscribing in dolphindb?

Is there a way to re-subscribe a stream table after I unsubscribe it?
I have a scenario: I subscribe a stream table, but I change the handler's logic, so I want to refresh the handler function and re-subscribe the stream table from the offset of the last subscribed message.

Answer (score 0):

The persistOffset in the subscribeTable function is a Boolean value that indicates whether to persist the offset of the latest processed subscription data. The persistently saved offset is used for re-subscription and can be obtained through the getTopicProcessedOffset function. The default value is false.